Does there exist an integral domain and a "non-trivial pair" $a,b$ s.t. $a^n\mid b$ for all $n$?
Let $R$ be an integral domain. We say $a\in R$ is a factor of $b\in R$, or $a\mid b$, if exists $c\in R$ s.t. $b=ac$.
I want to know if exists a domain $R$ and $a,b\in R$ s.t. $a$ is not a unit, $b\ne 0$ and $a^n\mid b$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z_+$.
If $R$ is noetherian, then Krull's intersection theorem states that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb Z_+} Ra^n=\{ 0 \}$,
which means such pair of $a,b$ can not exist in noetherian domains.
But what about non-noetherian case?

A way you might have "invented" Anne's answer below is to think to yourself: "I need a ring with elements $a$ and $b$, such that $b/a^n$ also lies in the ring for all $n > 0$. OK - what about the ring $\Bbb Z[A, B, B/A, B/A^2, \dotsc]$?" Then you have to do some work to define it and check it's an integral domain and $A$ is not a unit etc. It helps to construct it as a subring of $\Bbb Q(A, B)$, for example. It is actually a special case of Anne's answer, with $G = \Bbb Z^2$, which is in some sense the simplest non-Archimedean ordered group.

Thanks! Then it seems the following example also works. Is it correct?

Let $k$ be a field and $k(x,y)$ the field of rational functions with two intermediates. Then $k(x,y)$'s subring $$R=k[x,y,\frac{x}{y},\frac{x}{y^2},\cdots,\frac{x}{y^n},\cdots] $$ and $a=y\in R, b=x\in R$ will work. (That $y$ is not a unit in $R$ acn be argued as follows: Since elements of $R$ has the form $\frac{xf(x,y)}{y^n}+g(x,y)$ ($f(x,y), g(x,y)\in k[x,y]$), if we assume $y$ is a unit, then exists $f,g$ s.t. $\frac{xf(x,y)}{y^n}+g(x,y)=\frac 1y$, or $xf(x,y)+y^ng(x,y)=y^{n-1}$. Then $g$ must be $0$, and $xf(x,y)=y^{n-1}$, which is absurd by setting $x=0,y=1$).

Also used last week here $\ \ $

An example is
$$R=\Bbb Z[G_+],$$
where $G$ is any non-Archimedean ordered group.

Thanks for your answer!

Some remark on Anne's answer:
Let $G$ be commutative, ordered but non-archimedian, with operation written multiplicatively.

$R[G_+]$ is a domain:  $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ig_i$ and $\sum_{j=1}^m b_ih_i$ are non-zero members of $R$, and $g_1<\cdots<g_n$, $h_1<\cdots<h_m$, $a_n,b_m\ne 0$,
then $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ig_i)(\sum_{j=1}^m b_ih_i)=a_nb_mg_nh_m+\cdots\ne 0$.
Select $a,b\in G_+$ s.t. $a^n<b$ for all $b$. We claim $(1\cdot a)^n | 1\cdot b$ for all $n$ and $1\cdot a$ is not a unit.
This is because $ba^{-n}>e_G$ and $(1\cdot a)^n (1\cdot ba^{-n})=1\cdot b$.
Next we prove that $1\cdot a$ is not a unit. Note that inverse of $1\cdot a$    in $R[G]$ exists and is $1\cdot a^{-1}$.
If $x\in R[G_+]$, $(1\cdot a)x=1 $, then this also holds in $R[G]$, and $$x=(1\cdot a^{-1})(1\cdot a)x=1\cdot a^{-1}\notin R[G_+],$$ which is absurd.


Modeled on Anne Bauval's example, we can represent it as a space of analytic functions on $\mathbb{R}$.  Indeed, consider the set $\mathcal{P}$ consisting of polynomials of degree $1$ or $2$ with positive leading term, and the $0$ polynomial.  It is not very hard to check that the set of functions
$$\{ \exp(P(t))\ | \ P(t) \in \mathcal{P}, P(0)=0\}$$
is linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.  We now consider $A$ the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of functions on $\mathbb{R}$ spanned by $(\exp(P(t)))_{P(t) \in \mathcal{P}}$. Check that
$$\exp(t)^n \mid \exp(t^2)$$
for all $n$, and $\exp(t)$ is not invertible in $A$.
